# .htaccess rewrite rules . Not able to login

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I am trying to write a rule to remove .php from my urls.

```bash
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

All my url's are working as expected but one of the url for login into my admin panel `http://localhost/admin/login.php` seems to have stopped working. The admin page post login redirects again to the `http://localhost/admin/index.php` page.

Can anyone guide me on what wrong am I doing?

Comment: where are you supposed to be taken to ? admin index after you have logged in seems fairly normal

Comment: I should be redirected to http://localhost/admin/index.php

Comment: `http://localhost/admin/login.php` should be redirected to `http://localhost/admin/index.php` ?

Comment: Yes Correct @Shafizadeh.